# pdf combobox interraction using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf

I'm using Nuance Power PDF. I have 2 combo-boxes like this:

```
cb1:  
A  
B  
C 



cb2:  
1  
2
```

Both of them have a keystroke code like this:

```
if( event.willCommit ) { 
    if(event.value == "") this.resetForm(["tH"]); else SetFieldValues(event.value); 
}
```

I have a textbox "tH" and the Document Javascript looks like this:

```
function SetFieldValues(cDeptName)   
{  
  if(this.getField("cb1").value=="A" && this.getField("cb2").value=="1")  
{  
this.getField("tH").value = "Yes";  
}    
else  
{  
  this.getField("tH").value ="No";   
}  
}
```

I'm trying to test the code and say if cb1 is A and cb2 is 1 then place Yes in the textbox, but it is giving me a No for 1 and Yes for 2.

I would also like to have Yes in green and No in red, if that is possible.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put this to rest. Here is how I fixed it:
Changed the keystroke code like this for cb2:

```
if( event.willCommit ) { 
    if(event.value == "") this.resetForm(["tH"]); else SetFieldValues(this.getField("cb1").value,event.value); 
}
```

like this for cb1:

```
if( event.willCommit ) { 
    if(event.value == "") this.resetForm(["tH"]); else SetFieldValues(event.value,this.getField("cb2").value); 
}
```

Changed the Document code like this:

```
function SetFieldValues(x,y)     
{    
  if(x=="A" && y=="1")  
{  
this.getField("tH").value = "Yes";  
}    
else  
{  
  this.getField("tH").value ="No";   
}  
}
```

This fixed it.